# Dynamic memory allocation for structure, but what about its int or double members

Tags: c, pointers, memory, structure

I will be very thankful for looking at my code and telling me whether if I create a structure for which I am dynamically allocating memory, should I dynamically allocate memory also for the structure's elements that are int or double?

As it can be seen in the example below, I use malloc only for those elements of the structure which size can change, namely strings. I tried to use malloc for int or double variables (elements of the structure), but everything worked fine until I tried to use the function printf on them.

It refused to work because printf("%d", [structure]->[int element]) was not correct.

So I changed the code and int and double structure members are processed with the malloc and realloc functions. Is this approach correct?

Would it be expected and even possible to use malloc and realloc for int or double structure members/elements? How to use printf on them later on?

```
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#define LICZBA 2
#define SIZE 256

typedef struct ksiazka{
   char * imie;
   char * nazwisko;
   char * tytul;
   int numerkat;
   double cena;
}rekord;

rekord * rekordnew(){
   rekord *r;
   r=malloc(sizeof(rekord));
   r->imie=NULL;
   r->nazwisko=NULL;
   r->tytul=NULL;
   r->numerkat=0;
   r->cena=0;
   return r;
}

void rekordfree(rekord *r){
   if (r->imie) free (r->imie);
   if (r->nazwisko) free (r-> nazwisko);
   if (r-> tytul) free (r-> tytul);
   //if (r-> numerkat) free (r->numerkat);
   //if (r-> cena) free (r-> cena); 
   free (r);
}

void wpiszimie(rekord *pr, char im[SIZE]){
   (*pr).imie=realloc(pr->imie, strlen(im)+1);
   strcpy(pr->imie, im);
}

void wpisznazwisko(rekord *pr, char nazw[SIZE]){
   pr->nazwisko=realloc(pr->nazwisko, strlen(nazw)+1);
   strcpy(pr->nazwisko, nazw);
}

void wpisztytul(rekord *pr, char tyt[SIZE]){
   pr->tytul=realloc(pr->tytul, strlen(tyt)+1);
   strcpy(pr->tytul, tyt);
}

void wpisznumerkat(rekord *pr, int numer){
 //  pr->numerkat=realloc(pr->numerkat, sizeof(int));
   pr->numerkat=numer;
}

void wpiszcena(rekord *pr, double cen){
 //  pr->cena=realloc(pr->cena,sizeof(double));
   pr->cena=cen;
}


int main(){
  rekord *r[LICZBA];
  char bufor[SIZE];
  int i, number;
  double number2;

  for(i=0;i<LICZBA;i++){
     r[i]=rekordnew();
  }

  for(i=0;i<LICZBA;i++){
    printf("Podaj tytuł książki");
    scanf("%s", bufor);
    wpisztytul(r[i],bufor);
    printf("Podaj imię autora książki");
    if (scanf("%s", bufor)==1)wpiszimie(r[i],bufor);
    printf("Podaj nazwisko autora książki");
    if (scanf("%s", bufor)==1)wpisznazwisko(r[i],bufor);
    printf("Podaj numer katalogowy książki");
    if (scanf("%d", &number)==1)wpisznumerkat(r[i],number);
    printf("Podaj cenę książki");
    if (scanf("%lf", &number2)==1)wpiszcena(r[i],number2);
    }

    for(i=0;i<LICZBA;i++){
    printf("Tytuł książki");
    printf("%s", r[i]->tytul);
    printf("Imię autora książki");
    printf("%s", r[i]->imie);
    printf("Nazwisko autora książki");
    printf("%s", r[i]->nazwisko);
    printf("Numer katalogowy książki");
    printf("%d", r[i]->numerkat);
    printf("Cena książki");
    printf("%lf", r[i]->cena);

  } 
 return 0;
}
```

Comment: they are not pointers - you don't need to allocate memory for them, only for whole structure

Comment: printf("%d", [structure].[int element])

Comment: "should I dynamically allocate memory also for the structure's elements that are int or double?", you can't, because they are not pointers, using malloc return the address of what you dynamically created, and that should be handled by pointers, not int or double.

Comment: Which line(s) "were not correct"?  In what way(s) were they not correct?

Comment: the returned value from members of the malloc family of functions should be checked to assure the operation was successful, before actually using the returned value.

Comment: this line: scanf("%s", bufor); 1) is missing the check to assure the operation was successful.. 2) in general, the format string for scanf() should contain a leading ' ' (space) to skip over white space (like the newline) that is left in the buffer. 3) scanf does not append a nul byte to a string input, so that has to be performed in the code, otherwise a printf() of that variable will continue printing until a nul byte is encountered, resulting undefined behaviour and probably to a seg fault event

Comment: calls to realloc() should always not update the current pointer until after the new pointer is checked to assure the operation was successful

Comment: the free() function specifically checks for a NULL pointer, so there is no need for the code to make the same check.

Answer (score 3):

I cannot see any severe errors in your code though reasoning about it would be easier for me if you had written it in English.

As you do `malloc(sizeof(rekord))` you allocate memory to hold all members of a `rekord`.  That is three `char *` pointers, an `int` and a `double`.  You can write to those members immediately, no further allocation is needed.  Of course, writing to a `char *` member is not really useful unless you are assigning it a pointer to some `char` buffer which you'd in turn obtain via `malloc`.  For the `int` and `double` this is neither needed nor possible.  So your code is correct here.

A few minor remarks, though:

- You should check the return value of `malloc`.  If it fails, it will return `NULL`.  You should check for this (rare) event and handle the error if it happens.  Usually, terminating the program will be an appropriate action.
- You forgot to call `rekordfree` at the end.
- Using non-ASCII characters in your program source code may or may not work.  It should be avoided in portable programs.
- Your use of `scanf` for reading in the strings is a potential security hole as it might overrun the input buffer.  Since you are going to store the string in a `malloc()`ed buffer anyway, I suggest you use [`getline`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/getline) as a convenient and safe alternative.
- Consider adding more whitespace to your output (eg newlines via `\n`).  I guess that even if I understood the language, the output wouldn't be very easy to read as it's all on one line.  Printing a space or a tab (`\t`) at the end of the input prompts might also help improve the user experience.